# Fail to Keep windows service with Timer alive

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I have a windows service that I made for MY server...

I need to check every minute if there is some new info in my SQL Database.

So I made a windows service that create a Timer with interval of 1 minute.
But The windows service set the timer and ending the run.

It's goes like this:

1. - Starting Service
2. - Setting Timer with interval
3. - Finishing and exiting Service <-- I want to keep it alive

As you can see the Service exit and I want the Windows service to run every minute without stopping....

I can see in the **Event Viewer** that there are the "**Service started successfully**." And the "**Service stopped successfully**."

**What should I do?**

P.S : I thought Timer should work with out exit... or may I wrong?

***CODE:***

*Windows service:*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Utils.SetConfigFile();
                var ServiceToRun = new TaoTimer();
                ServiceToRun.Start(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
         }
```

*TaoTimer:*

```
public partial class TaoTimer : ServiceBase
{
    List<TimerModel> timerList;
    public TaoTimer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Started");
    }
    public void SetTimer(TimerModel timerModel)
    {
        int minute = 1000 * 60;
        try
        {
            AlertTimer at = new AlertTimer(timerModel, minute);
            at.Start();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Stopped");
    }
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Paused");
    }
    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Continuing");
    }
    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("ShutDowned");
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        SetTimerList();
    }
    protected void SetTimerList()//Read Config from xml and start the timer
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load(@"C:\TaoTimer\Data.xml");
        timerList = new List<TimerModel>(from d in root.Descendants("Timer")
                                         select new TimerModel(
                           d.Element("Id").Value.ToString(),
                           d.Element("Name").Value.ToString(),
                           d.Element("InterVal").Value.ToString(),
                           d.Element("TimeFormat").Value.ToString(),
                           d.Element("Day").Value.ToString(),
                           d.Element("TimeStamp").Value.ToString()));
        timerList.ForEach(i => SetTimer(i));
    }
}
```

*AlertTimer:*

```
public class AlertTimer
{
    static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public AlertTimer(TimerModel timerModel, int milliseconds)
    {
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e, timerModel));
        aTimer.Interval = milliseconds;
    }    
    public void Start()
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, TimerModel timerModel)
    {
        getAbsenceContacts.Start();<-- NEVER GETS HERE....
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the Windows Event Log for the unhandled exception that's keeping it from running.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Already done it... There is no unhandled exception there...

Comment: Are you getting the `Started` Event Log?

Comment: Yup, I will update my Question..

Comment: you mentioned you can see "service started successfully", but are you getting *your event log that you have in the Start*?

Comment: If you are referring to "Started" so Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually starting your service.  You're calling a method named Start, which is not part of the Windows Service class hierarchy it's just a method you've defined.  Your method runs and finishes, so the service exits.

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Utils.SetConfigFile();
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new TaoTimer() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
     }

public partial class TaoTimer : ServiceBase
{
    ...
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        SetTimerList();
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Started");
    }
    ....
}
```

and remove the Start method from TaoTimer entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your `AlertTimer` instances in something that will last the lifetime of the service (e.g. in a `List<AlertTimer>` declared as a field inside `TaoTimer`.

It's only really alluded to in the documentation for [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that timer's, in and of themselves, don't prevent themselves from being garbage collected. The example says:

```
    // Normally, the timer is declared at the class level, 
    // so that it stays in scope as long as it is needed. 
    // If the timer is declared in a long-running method,   
    // KeepAlive must be used to prevent the JIT compiler  
    // from allowing aggressive garbage collection to occur  
    // before the method ends. You can experiment with this 
    // by commenting out the class-level declaration and  
    // uncommenting the declaration below; then uncomment 
    // the GC.KeepAlive(aTimer) at the end of the method. 
    //System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
```

Now, whilst your timer's *are* declared at the class level inside of your `AlertTimer` class, there's nothing to stop the `AlertTimer` instances, themselves, from being collected. And the GC only keeps things alive that are transitively reachable. Once the `AlertTimer` instances are collectible, so are your `Timer` objects.